# Sourcecontrol for Clarion 6

Tags: version-control, clarion

We're still developing a bunch of our application in Clarion 6 Enterprise. I was wondering if anyone knows of a sourcecontrol system that works well with Clarion 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be surprised if the standard source control systems weren't just fine, e.g., Subversion.    Is there something special about Clarion 6 enterprise?

Comment: yes, all source files are name like projNm001.clw and projnm003.inc and a few other formats, but for not a single filename it is clear what's inside. That means you have to check in and out the entire project, which will be a pain when working with more than one person.

Comment: OK, so other than conceptual inconvenience, what's wrong with checking in and out an entire project?   Given the fact that the source file names are uninformative, unless you find a tool that specifically knows how Clarion maps file names to intelligable "content indicators", I doubt you can do better.

Comment: In addition, the .app files (which most Clarion users use) are binary. The *001.clw (etc) and *003.inc (etc) files are generated by the IDE from what's in the .app. C6 supported PVCS at one time, but its better to avoid that and use Git or VSS or really anything *outside* the C6 IDE. Collaboration is the issue with .app files, as @Sorskoot notes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Rick Martin has tools that allow Clarion to work with subversion and tortise version control systems.  They allow you to export the changed procedures to TXA's and import the changes back into the application.

One of the things I like about his system is that when a procedure is checked back into the Source Control System his tools will build a current version of your product so you can verify that the changes don't create compile errors.

The tools are not for sale though.  They come with your buying his consulting services.

Answer (score 1):

You're free to rename the modules in Clarion - so you're not bound to the existing generated names.

However that's not the root problem. the root problem is that you don't want to be editing CLW and INC files, you want to be editing the APP file. Otherwise your changes will be lost when the app regenerates.

You can use Subversion, or any other system, with app files - they're just binary files. From a rollback point of view this is fine.

Unfortunately though when you checkout an app you get the whole app. So no one else on the team can work on any other procedures in the app at the same time. If your apps are small then this is no big deal, but if you have a single-app system, or a system comprising of large apps, then it can become a hindrance.

The other disadvantage is that, being a binary file, it's not possible for the version control to merge files together - it's an all-or-nothing situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [TDC](http://www.tdcsoftware.com). It's more than just a VCS for Clarion because you also have a Tracking System.
By the way, TDC is written with Clarion.

Answer (score 0):

Look on Rick Martin presentation it's very useful, but not for sale :(

http://www.clarionlive.com/images/stories/videos/webinar11.wmv